# Union with System.Linq.IQueryable get errors

Tags: c#, .net, linq

i am trying to use union as follows :

```
var query1 = from c in dc.Hotel_Meals_TBLs
             where c.CHDLunch != "0" && c.CHDLunch != ""
             select new
             {
                 SERVICE_CODE = c.HotelCodeID,
                 SERVICE_NAME = c.HotelName,
                 ROOM_CATEGORY = "",
                 ROOM_TYPE = "",
                 VARIANCE_NAME = "CHILDLUNCH",
                 MARKET = "WW",
                 CONTRACT_BUSINESS_YEAR = "2014/2015",
                 CONTRACT_START_DATE = "01/11/2014",
                 CONTRACT_END_DATE = "30/10/2015",
                 TYPE = "CHILD POLICY",
                 CURRENCY = c.CurrencyCode,
                 PERIOD_NAME = "",
                 PERIOD_START_DATE = "",
                 PERIOD_END_DATE = "",
                 PRICE = c.Lunch,
                 PERCENTAGE = c.CHDLunch + "%",
                 NUM_TO_STAY = "",
                 NUM_TO_PAY = "",
                 PENALTY_TIME_LIMIT = "",
                 PENALTY_NO_DAY_BEFORE = "",
                 CHILD_REFERENCE = "",
                 TEXT = c.ChildPolicy
             };
var query2 = from c in dc.Hotel_Meals_TBLs
             from d in dc.HotelPeriod_TBLs
             from f in dc.HotelRoom_TBLs
             where c.HotelCodeID == d.HotelCodeID && c.HotelCodeID == f.HotelCodeID && f.DBL_HighSeason != 0 && d.PeriodName == "High"
             select new
             {
                 SERVICE_CODE = c.HotelCodeID,
                 SERVICE_NAME = c.HotelName,
                 ROOM_CATEGORY = f.RoomName,
                 ROOM_TYPE = "DBL",
                 VARIANCE_NAME = "",
                 MARKET = "WW",
                 CONTRACT_BUSINESS_YEAR = "2014/2015",
                 CONTRACT_START_DATE = "01/11/2014",
                 CONTRACT_END_DATE = "30/10/2015",
                 TYPE = "COST",
                 CURRENCY = c.CurrencyCode,
                 PERIOD_NAME = d.PeriodName,
                 PERIOD_START_DATE = d._From,
                 PERIOD_END_DATE = d._To,
                 PRICE = f.SGL_LowSeason,
                 PERCENTAGE = "",
                 NUM_TO_STAY = "",
                 NUM_TO_PAY = "",
                 PENALTY_TIME_LIMIT = "",
                 PENALTY_NO_DAY_BEFORE = "",
                 CHILD_REFERENCE = "",
                 TEXT = ""
             };
 var result = query1.Union(query2);
```

and i got this errors:

> `'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>'` does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload `'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Union<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)'` has some invalid arguments
>
> Instance argument: cannot convert from `'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>'` to `'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<AnonymousType#2>'`

truly i used this method many times without get errors...do you have any idea what is wrong in this query?

Comment: Try to use well-known type with all these fields rather than an anonymous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates that .NET thinks those two anonymous types are different. In order for two anonymous types to be the same they must have the same number of properties with the same names and types. I've gone through your property list and they appear to have the same names in the same order. However, it's possible you've got different types in these areas:

Type 1

```
PERIOD_START_DATE = ""
PERIOD_END_DATE = ""
PRICE = c.Lunch,
TEXT = c.ChildPolicy
```

Type 2

```
PERIOD_START_DATE = d._From
PERIOD_END_DATE = d._To
PRICE = f.SGL_LowSeason
TEXT = ""
```

Make sure that `d._From`, `d._To`, and `c.ChildPolicy` are all strings and that `c.Lunch` and `f.SGL_LowSeason` are the same type (e.g. maybe one is an `int` and the other is a `decimal`).

Comment: You are right [Here is dot net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/q7Pha8) (proof) that reports same error.

Comment: @Craig W. thank you so much for the help ,i work out just following your words.Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You have to create one ViewModel with all the properties you want and assign all the values to the viewmodel properties and in both the query the select statement will be like :

```
select new ViewModel{
    ViewmodelProperties = Value,
};
```

Like:

```
var query1 = from c in dc.Hotel_Meals_TBLs
         where c.CHDLunch != "0" && c.CHDLunch != ""
         select new ViewModel
         {
             SERVICE_CODE = c.HotelCodeID,
             SERVICE_NAME = c.HotelName,
             ROOM_CATEGORY = "",
             ROOM_TYPE = "",
             VARIANCE_NAME = "CHILDLUNCH",
             MARKET = "WW",
             CONTRACT_BUSINESS_YEAR = "2014/2015",
             CONTRACT_START_DATE = "01/11/2014",
             CONTRACT_END_DATE = "30/10/2015",
             TYPE = "CHILD POLICY",
             CURRENCY = c.CurrencyCode,
             PERIOD_NAME = "",
             PERIOD_START_DATE = "",
             PERIOD_END_DATE = "",
             PRICE = c.Lunch,
             PERCENTAGE = c.CHDLunch + "%",
             NUM_TO_STAY = "",
             NUM_TO_PAY = "",
             PENALTY_TIME_LIMIT = "",
             PENALTY_NO_DAY_BEFORE = "",
             CHILD_REFERENCE = "",
             TEXT = c.ChildPolicy
         };
var query2 = from c in dc.Hotel_Meals_TBLs
         from d in dc.HotelPeriod_TBLs
         from f in dc.HotelRoom_TBLs
         where c.HotelCodeID == d.HotelCodeID && c.HotelCodeID == f.HotelCodeID && f.DBL_HighSeason != 0 && d.PeriodName == "High"
         select new ViewModel
         {
             SERVICE_CODE = c.HotelCodeID,
             SERVICE_NAME = c.HotelName,
             ROOM_CATEGORY = f.RoomName,
             ROOM_TYPE = "DBL",
             VARIANCE_NAME = "",
             MARKET = "WW",
             CONTRACT_BUSINESS_YEAR = "2014/2015",
             CONTRACT_START_DATE = "01/11/2014",
             CONTRACT_END_DATE = "30/10/2015",
             TYPE = "COST",
             CURRENCY = c.CurrencyCode,
             PERIOD_NAME = d.PeriodName,
             PERIOD_START_DATE = d._From,
             PERIOD_END_DATE = d._To,
             PRICE = f.SGL_LowSeason,
             PERCENTAGE = "",
             NUM_TO_STAY = "",
             NUM_TO_PAY = "",
             PENALTY_TIME_LIMIT = "",
             PENALTY_NO_DAY_BEFORE = "",
             CHILD_REFERENCE = "",
             TEXT = ""
         };
 var result = query1.Union(query2);
```

Comment: When you use ViewModel, the return type for both the query will be the same and then we can use union in both the queries.

Comment: You don't have to do this. It works fine with anonymous types as long as you ensure the two `select` clauses create objects with the same number of properties, names, and types.

Comment: Yes @Craig you are right, viewmodel provide an assurity, that  we are using same number of properties, name and types.

Comment: My point was that your post said, "You *have* to create one ViewModel..." (emphasis mine) and I was simply trying to point out that that wasn't true, you do not have to create a ViewModel. I would argue that if he's not using the results outside of the current method creating a ViewModel is actually more of a pain than using the anonymous class.